# Easiest possible way to add dynamic list(int) items C#

Tags: asp.net, list, c#-4.0

Suggest me the easiest possible way to add dynamic list(int) items.
i.e

```
List<int> list1=new List<int>();
list1[0]=1;
list1[1]=2;
list1[2]=3;
.
.
.
list[n]=n; 
int finalResult= list1[0]+list1[2]+list1[3]+....list1[n]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq's Sum() method works on any genericized enumerable source.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734.aspx

```
public static double Sum<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, double> selector
)
```

Nice sample directly from http://www.dotnetperls.com/sum.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // Declare two collections of int elements.
    //
    int[] array1 = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
    List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 7 };

    //
    // Use Sum extension on their elements.
    //
    int sum1 = array1.Sum();
    int sum2 = list1.Sum();

    //
    // Write results to screen.
    //
    Console.WriteLine(sum1);
    Console.WriteLine(sum2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's [Sum()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338442.aspx) extension method:

```
int finalResult = list1.Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to generate a sequential list and get its sum:

```
    List<int> list1 = Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToList();
    int finalResult = list1.Sum();
```

if you are not using linq, do it like this:

```
    int finalResult = 0;
    foreach (int i in list1)
        finalResult += i;
```